# Laravel/LaraCSV Managing Complex Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running into some issues with my Collection/Model relationships with regards to LaraCSV. Here is its documentation: https://github.com/usmanhalalit/laracsv#full-documentation. I have 3 models that interact right now: Doctor, Patient, Script

```
Doctor belongsToMany Patient
Patient belongsToMany Doctor

Patient hasMany Script
Script belongsTo Patient
```

I also created a relationship link inside of my Doctor model that can be used to tie Doctor to Script, but does not appear to work in this instance:

```
public function scripts() {
    $this->load(['patients.scripts' => function($query) use (&$relation) {
        $relation = $query;
    }]);

    return $relation;
}
```

What I am attempting to do is allow admin staff and our users to download CSV files that contain all of their scripts. While this works fine for admin staff as I can reference the models directly, I am not able to make it work for users because they are tied to the doctors, and I cannot seem to tie this into scripts as normal. Here is a perfectly working version for admin staff:

```
$doctors = Doctor::orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->get();
$patients = Patient::orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->get();
$scripts = Script::orderBy('prescribe_date', 'desc')->get();

$csvExporter->beforeEach(function ($script) use ($doctors, $patients) {
    $patient = $patients->where('id', $script->patient_id)->first();
    $doctor = $patient->doctors->first();
    $script->patient = $patient->full_name;
    $script->doctor = $doctor->full_name;
});
```

Here is how the user-specific version appears:

```
$doctors = User::
    find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
$patients = Patient::orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->get();
$scripts = $doctors->scripts()->get();
```

Trying to chain in my Doctor model `scripts()` function results in an error: `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::scripts does not exist.`

```
$doctors = User::
    find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
$patients = array();
$scripts = array();
foreach ($doctors as $doctor_fe) {

    foreach ($doctor_fe->patients as $patient_fe) {
        $patients[] = $patient_fe;

        foreach ($patient_fe->scripts as $script_fe) {
            $scripts[] = $script_fe;
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to pull the information using arrays, but unfortunately, it must be a Collection passed in via this error: `Argument 1 passed to Laracsv\Export::addCsvRows() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection, array given`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled by placing all of the patients belonging to the user's doctors through a foreach loop, then using another one to grab the patient's id. I then took the patient's id array and used the whereIn function to compare the Script's patient_id field to get the correct strips.

```
$doctors = User::
    find(Auth::user()->id)
    ->doctors()
    ->orderBy('last_name', 'asc')
    ->get();

$patients_array = array();

foreach ($doctors as $doctor_fe) {
    $patients_fe = $doctor_fe->patients;
        foreach ($patients_fe as $patient_fe) {
            $patients_array[] = $patient_fe->id;
         }
     }

$patients = Patient::orderBy('last_name', 'asc')->get();
$scripts = Script::whereIn('patient_id', $patients_array)->get();

$csvExporter->beforeEach(function ($script) use ($doctors, $patients) {
    $patient = $patients->where('id', $script->patient_id)->first();
    $patient_initials = substr($patient->first_name, 0, 1) . substr($patient->last_name, 0, 1);
    $doctor = $patient->doctors->first();
    $script->patient = $patient_initials;
    $script->doctor = $doctor->full_name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I interpret you question correctly, you want to get all scripts of all patients of a doctor. Laravel provides the `hasManyThrough()` Method for this:

```
class Doctor extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the scripts for the patient.
     */
    public function scripts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Script::class, App\Patient::class);
    }
}
```

The first param is the model you want to get (the scripts); the 2nd param is the intermediate model (the patient).

To use it:

```
$doctor = Doctor::first();
$scripts = $doctor->scripts;
```